# Dataset Annotation With two labels instead of single label for object detection

Tags: python-3.x, object-detection, data-annotations, labeling

"Hi,
I want to annotate my dataset with two-labels and then train two models to predict both the labels. Which annotation tool I can use for it. I searched around but could not found anything related.

Thanks."